# SQL: How to Select multiple row with same ID against an argument

Tags: sql

I have an `Invoice` table with these columns:

```
InvoiceID, ProductID, Qty, Sum, Location, etc
```

Primary key is `InvoiceID + ProductID`

A single `Invoice` can have more than one row so a single invoice will look like this:

```
InvoiceID | ProductID | Qty | Sum   | Location
----------------------------------------------
1000      | 123       | 2   | 20.00 | Loc1
1000      | 321       | 4   | 12.00 | Loc1
1000      | 145       | 1   | 03.50 | Loc1
1000      | 134       | 1   | 10.00 | Loc1
1001      | 123       | 1   | 20.00 | Loc1
1002      | 321       | 1   | 03.50 | Loc1
1002      | 145       | 1   | 10.00 | Loc1
1002      | 134       | 1   | 20.00 | Loc1
```

So what I want to do is write a SQL statement to exclude all distinct `InvoiceID`

So the result would come out to be

```
1000,1001,1002
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT InvoiceID 
FROM 
  Invoice 
WHERE ProductID=123
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exclude all distinct InvoiceID's then try this,

```
select InvoiceID from Invoice 
where ProductID=123
group by InvoiceID having count(InvoiceID) > 1
```